# Is there a way to avoid MOVE errors on script restore?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

I've searched for a while this problem and can't figure out a solution if there's none.

Every week we get new databases from clients. I developed a tool to restore our own databases in order to keep all databases to keep with the client ones.
The tool works for some databases but on others I get some errors because of the log files.

My script for restoring the database is the following

```
USE [master] 
ALTER DATABASE[MyDataBase] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE 
RESTORE DATABASE[MyDataBase] 
FROM  DISK = N'MyDataBase.bak' 
WITH NOUNLOAD, 
REPLACE, STATS = 5 
ALTER DATABASE[MyDataBase] SET MULTI_USER
```

I know if I use the MOVE command I can get over my problem, the thing is I have no way to know the files beforehand, meaning I can't really write any custom code to restore the databases.

Digging a bit deeper I found that I could print all my log files from the database with the following command

```
SELECT 
  DB_NAME([database_id]) [database_name]
, [file_id]
, [type_desc] [file_type]
, [name] [logical_name]
, [physical_name]
FROM sys.[master_files]
WHERE [database_id] IN (DB_ID('MyDataBase'))
ORDER BY [type], DB_NAME([database_id]);
```

but the files presented there have completly different names from the ones I get the error on.

Another important thing to note is that if I restore the database and then try to restore through tsql I can do the restore but I have a Server Agent Job renaming the files in order to keep things clean and after running that I'm unable to restore the database again giving the same errors that I was getting before restoring manually.

I have no clue if what I'm trying to achieve is achievable and if so how to achieve it. If anyone could give me some lights it would be amazing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RESTORE FILELISTONLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-filelistonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) will tell you the files, and you can build up the RESTORE ... WITH MOVE from that:

EG

```
--backup database a to disk='c:\temp\a.bak'

declare @fn nvarchar(255) = 'c:\temp\a.bak';
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = concat('restore filelistonly from disk=''',@fn,'''');
declare @targetFolder nvarchar(max) = 'c:\temp\customer_123';
declare @dbname sysname = 'a_123';

declare @t table
(
LogicalName nvarchar(128),--,   --Logical name of the file.
PhysicalName    nvarchar(260),--    Physical or operating-system name of the file.
Type    char(1),--  The type of file, one of:
FileGroupName   nvarchar(128) NULL, --  Name of the filegroup that contains the file.
Size    numeric(20,0),--    Current size in bytes.
MaxSize numeric(20,0),--    Maximum allowed size in bytes.
FileID  bigint,--   File identifier, unique within the database.
CreateLSN   numeric(25,0),--    Log sequence number at which the file was created.
DropLSN numeric(25,0) NULL, --  The log sequence number at which the file was dropped. If the file has not been dropped, this value is NULL.
UniqueID    uniqueidentifier,-- Globally unique identifier of the file.
ReadOnlyLSN numeric(25,0) NULL, --  Log sequence number at which the filegroup containing the file changed from read-write to read-only (the most recent change),--.
ReadWriteLSN    numeric(25,0) NULL, --  Log sequence number at which the filegroup containing the file changed from read-only to read-write (the most recent change),--.
BackupSizeInBytes   bigint, --  Size of the backup for this file in bytes.
SourceBlockSize int, -- Block size of the physical device containing the file in bytes (not the backup device),--.
FileGroupID int,-- ID of the filegroup.
LogGroupGUID    uniqueidentifier NULL, --   NULL.
DifferentialBaseLSN numeric(25,0) NULL, --  For differential backups, changes with log sequence numbers greater than or equal to DifferentialBaseLSN are included in the differential 
DifferentialBaseGUID    uniqueidentifier NULL, --   For differential backups, the unique identifier of the differential base.
IsReadOnly  bit,--  1 = The file is read-only.
IsPresent   bit,--  1 = The file is present in the backup.
TDEThumbprint   varbinary(32) NULL, --  Shows the thumbprint of the Database Encryption Key. The encryptor thumbprint is a SHA-1 hash of the certificate with which the key is encrypted. For information about database encryption, see Transparent Data Encryption (TDE),--.
SnapshotURL nvarchar(360)-- NULL    The URL for the Azure snapshot of the database file contained in the FILE_SNAPSHOT backup. Returns NULL if no FILE_SNAPSHOT backup.
);
insert into @t
exec (@sql);


with q as 
(
select concat('restore database ',@dbname,' from disk=''',@fn,''' with ') l
union all
select concat('
move ''',LogicalName,''' to ''', @targetFolder, '\', LogicalName, case [type] when 'D' then '.mdf' when 'L' then '.ldf' else null end, ''' , ')
from @t 
union all
select 'RECOVERY, STATS = 10'
)
select @sql = STRING_AGG(l,'
')
from q;


print (@sql);
exec (@sql );
```

Comment: Will try and will give feedback! It's a work question so I wont be ready to tell it really works untill Monday, but I took a look at FILEISTONLY and the bak file has the paths from the client so I'm guessing that even after mapping all the files it still gives an error because of the bak files.
Thanks for the code mate :)

Comment: The idea is to ignore the paths and filenames in the backup, and move all the database files to a single directory, with a filename constructed from the LogicalName of the file.

Comment: Yeah! The problem was that I could not get all the names in order to construct the names. What is happening is we have 2 states of the same database. The PRE update and the POS update. And since the names are the same we have to rename them and that is causing some problems.

Cross fingers for it to work using VB.NET though eheh

Comment: Worked like a charm
Just a heads up...STRING_AGG can't be used with all SMSS 2016 so I went with COALESCE for the concat
Thanks for the script David Browne :)